# same sql query different results ?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Sql query

```
SELECT tt.ID_Partenaire, tt.Nom_Societe,tt.Image_Societe, tt.id_activite 
                FROM affiliate AS a 
                RIGHT JOIN 
                  (SELECT partenaires.ID_Partenaire, 
                  partenaires.Nom_Societe, partenaires.Image_Societe, partenaires.id_activite,
                        IFNULL(SUM(c.montant_real),0) AS mt1 
                    FROM partenaires
                        LEFT JOIN commande AS c 
                    ON partenaires.ID_Partenaire=c.id_partenaire 
                    GROUP BY partenaires.ID_Partenaire 
                  )AS tt 
            ON a.id_partenaire= tt.ID_Partenaire 
            GROUP BY tt.ID_Partenaire 
            ORDER BY (IFNULL(SUM(a.montat),0) + mt1) DESC 
            LIMIT 20
```

I have two server :

1. **Version du serveur : 5.7.11-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL) -locally-**
2. **Server version: 10.1.25-MariaDB-1~jessie - mariadb.org binary distribution - host -**

When i execute it on these servers, each one of them give me a different result.

I think the problem is in the `ORDER BY`

As a solution i made :

```
SELECT ID_Partenaire, Nom_Societe, Image_Societe, id_activite 
      FROM (SELECT tt.ID_Partenaire, tt.Nom_Societe,tt.Image_Societe, 
             tt.id_activite, 
             (IFNULL(SUM(a.montat),0) + mt1) as mm
                FROM affiliate AS a 
                RIGHT JOIN 
                  (SELECT partenaires.ID_Partenaire, 
                       partenaires.Nom_Societe, partenaires.Image_Societe, 
                       partenaires.id_activite,
                        IFNULL(SUM(c.montant_real),0) AS mt1 
                    FROM partenaires
                        LEFT JOIN commande AS c 
                    ON partenaires.ID_Partenaire=c.id_partenaire 
                    GROUP BY partenaires.ID_Partenaire 
                  )AS tt 
            ON a.id_partenaire= tt.ID_Partenaire 
            GROUP BY tt.ID_Partenaire 
            ORDER BY mm DESC 
            LIMIT 20) AS k
```

I am really confused because MySql does not give me any error but gives different result, i have other queries and i am afraid that he is doing the same for them !

Comment: Check if the two servers are using different engines

Comment: In what way are the results different? Do you definitely have identical data on both servers?

Comment: Assuming `ID_Partenaire` is the PK on `partenaires` it shouldn't be a problem; but if it isn't, you should note selecting non-aggregated fields that are not grouped on can yield varying results, and is not even allowed by many (any?) RDBMS outside the MySQL family.

Comment: @kai same engine -i think you mean type, it is InnoDB for all tables-

Comment: @JeffUK yes, identical data on both servers

Comment: @Uueerdo yes, ID_Partenaire is the PK on partenaires but it is a problem !!

Comment: May I suggest that you take one subquery at a time and run it on both the servers to see where exactly the difference is and add that detail into the question?

Comment: @tarekbaz and what is the different between the results on the two servers? Different data, different ordering, different columns?

Comment: @JeffUK different ordering => Different data because there is limit 20, but same columns !

Comment: @DhruvSaxena subquery gives same results

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference using [explain report](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html). Just run `explain extended SELECT ID_Partenaire, Nom_Societe...`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the limit after the order by block. 'limit' and 'order by' is in same level 'limit' done before the 'order by' happen, so give different result

try something like this

```
SELECT ID_Partenaire,
  Nom_Societe,
  Image_Societe,
  id_activite
FROM
  (SELECT tt.ID_Partenaire,
    tt.Nom_Societe,
    tt.Image_Societe,
    tt.id_activite,
    (IFNULL(SUM(a.montat),0) + mt1) AS mm
  FROM affiliate                    AS a
  RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT partenaires.ID_Partenaire,
      partenaires.Nom_Societe,
      partenaires.Image_Societe,
      partenaires.id_activite,
      IFNULL(SUM(c.montant_real),0) AS mt1
    FROM partenaires
    LEFT JOIN commande AS c
    ON partenaires.ID_Partenaire=c.id_partenaire
    GROUP BY partenaires.ID_Partenaire
    )AS tt ON a.id_partenaire= tt.ID_Partenaire
  GROUP BY tt.ID_Partenaire
  ORDER BY mm DESC
  ) AS k LIMIT 20
```